# CiviCRM Wordpress Member Sync w/ Wordpress Groups Plugin: How to add CiviMember to WP Group

Tags: wordpress, civimember

I have the latest CiviCRM and Wordpress installed. I've got the latest Groups plugin for Wordpress (https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/), and the CiviCRM Wordpress Member Sync plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/).

I've set up a CiviCRM Membership Type of **Membership A**, and a Group in Wordpress called **Member**

What I thought I would be able to set up in the Member Sync plugin Association Rule is tick a checkbox or something to select a Wordpress Group to add the Member too. I'm not seeing this in the plugin settings dashboard anywhere or options.

So when the plugin syncs it adds a new  Wordpress User from **Membership A** from CiviCRM as a (Subscriber)---that's working.

But the new WP User was only added to the default **Registered** group in Groups. I need the  new user to be added to the **Member** group in Wordpress.

Please help, as this is integral to hiding pages for members only eyes.

FYI: I have the sync plugin set to **Capabilities** (not Roles) as I need the default Wordpress roles for another plugin.

The description for the civi members sync plugin says it works with Groups, but I just can't see how! https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/#installation

I'm hoping one of you Wordpress +CiviCRM experts can help me. I've been scratching my head the whole day!

Cheers,
Tracy

Comment: Hi Tracy, the Groups compatibility is limited to content viewing restrictions. You probably noticed that the CWMS custom capabilities show up in Groups and up to v2.8.0 this was how Groups implemented read access to content. Since v2.8.0, however, the Groups plugin has changed how this works. It's on my to-do list to implement what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the update Christian. I'll watch out for the update. In the meantime, I'm using the Civi WP Groups Sync plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be resolved in [CiviCRM WordPress Member Sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/) version 0.4 which was released today. Group membership can now be applied via association rules, which means that the Groups v2.8.0+ schema for access control is now fully supported.

Comment: Also if you use roles with this plugin you could make use of User Role Editor Content Restrictions: https://www.role-editor.com/documentation/content-view-restrictions/.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the suggestion but I need to keep to capabilities as another WP plugin works on the standard WP roles.

Comment: Thank you so much for updating the plugin Christian. It works perfectly!

Comment: You can make new roles.