# Issues with Civi Member Sync and Groups Plugin

Tags: wordpress, civimember, sync

I have the latest CiviCRM and Wordpress installed. I've got the latest Groups plugin for Wordpress (https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/), and the CiviCRM Wordpress Member Sync plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-wp-member-sync/).

I am having the exact same problem as detailed by the [user in this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31607/civicrm-wordpress-member-sync-w-wordpress-groups-plugin-how-to-add-civimember). The issue being users seem to be only being placed in the default group and not in the group created and connected to the capability as defined in CWMS.

My desired flow is:
CiviCRM Contribute form -> Adds membership to Civi -> User is synced -> User is placed into Member Group 1.

Currently, all seems to be working except for the last step. The users seem to be only be placed in the default group.

Thanks so much for any help.

**Screenshots**

[image]

Comment: I can't replicate this on my dev site(s). Can you post some screenshots of your settings pages?

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks so much - screenshots attached. It is currently sitting on a dev site and cron is not running - if that impacts on the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from your screenshots, Groups is either (1) not installed or (2) not configured. Here's what you should see:

[image]

Note the extra column which shows the Groups groups.

Comment: Sorry Christian, I had Groups deactivated when I took the screenshots. I've updated it now, and I do see the Groups column now.